# How can I remove Date from Time Object?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to save the time [hh:mm:ss] in excel cell using Apache POI. The code which I have written is as Follow-

```
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("dateFormat.xls");
  HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  HSSFSheet sheet = hssfworkbook.createSheet("new sheet");
  HSSFCellStyle cs = hssfworkbook.createCellStyle();
  HSSFDataFormat df = hssfworkbook.createDataFormat();
  cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("h:mm:ss"));
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
  HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)0);
  //cell.setCellValue(new Time(567898));
  cell.setCellValue(new Time(1, 6, 55));
  cell.setCellStyle(cs);
  hssfworkbook.write(out);
  out.close();
```

Now the issue is that it includes date along with the time.  when I am doing `sum` of the cells in excel sheet generated by this code. It is giving `incorrect` result.

```
 cell.setCellValue(new Time(3, 4, 4));  --->01-01-1970  03:04:04 AM [in excel sheet]
 cell2.setCellValue(new Time(1, 6, 51)); --->01-01-1970  01:06:55 AM [in excel sheet]
```

Another way I tried giving `String` value, in this case result is `Zero`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working code for this problem is:

```
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("dateFormat.xls");
  HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  HSSFSheet sheet = hssfworkbook.createSheet("new sheet");
  HSSFCellStyle cs = hssfworkbook.createCellStyle();
  HSSFDataFormat df = hssfworkbook.createDataFormat();
  HSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(hssfworkbook);

  cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("h:mm:ss"));
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
  HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)0);


  cell.setCellFormula("TIME(0,3,24)");//this method only sets the formula string and does not calculate the formula value
  cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);//Set the cells type (numeric, formula or string)

  evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);// it evaluates the formula, and saves the result of the formula
  cell.setCellStyle(cs);



  HSSFRow row2 = sheet.createRow((short)1);
  HSSFCell cell2 = row2.createCell((short)0);


  cell2.setCellFormula("TIME(0,9,54)");
  cell2.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
  evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell2);
  cell2.setCellStyle(cs);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set cell's style in order for format to work:

```
cell.setStyle(cs);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I forgot to mention I had already written `cell.setStyle(cs)` in my code. Can you please suggest some other solution.